# Perl subroutine returning unexpected value

Tags: perl

I am extending CGI and trying to add a simple router to it, just for fun.

Here are my Test::More tests

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Test::More tests => 4;

use CGI::Router;

my $router = CGI::Router->new;
my $resp;

## 1. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';

$resp = $router->connect('GET /', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello 1';
});
# print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello 1' );

## 2. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/hello';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';

$resp = $router->connect('GET /hello', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello 2';
});
# print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello 2' );

## 3. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/hello/kitty';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';

$resp = $router->connect('GET /hello/:who', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello 3';
});
# print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello 3' );

## 4. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/hello/kitty/kat';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';

$resp = $router->connect('GET /hello/:who/:what', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello kitty kat';
});
# print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello kitty kat' );

$router->run;
```

Here is my module

```
package CGI::Router;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'CGI';
use Carp;

use Data::Dumper;

sub connect {
  my ( $self, $req, $subr ) = @_;

  $self->{routes} //= {};
  $self->{env} //= \%ENV;

  if ( ! exists $self->{routes}->{$req} ) {
    $self->{routes}->{$req} = {
      handler => $subr,
      pattern => $self->build_pattern( $req ),
      method => $req =~ /^(GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)/
    };
  } else {
    Carp::croak( "Similar request already exists $req!" );
  }

  # Get current request destination
  # TODO: Add that stupid IIS HTTP header
  $self->{destination} = $self->{env}->{REQUEST_URI};
  $self->{method} = $self->{env}->{REQUEST_METHOD};

  return $self->mapper();
}

sub mapper {
  my $self = shift;

  my $router;
  my @params;

  foreach my $key ( keys %{ $self->{routes} } ) {
    my $route = $self->{routes}->{$key};

    if ( $self->{method} eq $route->{method} &&
      $self->{destination} =~ $route->{pattern} ) {

      @params = $self->{destination} =~ $route->{pattern};

      $router = $route;
    }
  }

  return $router->{handler}->( @params );
}

sub build_pattern {
  my ( $self, $pattern ) = @_;

  $pattern =~ s/(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)\s?//i;

  $pattern = do {
    # Replace something like /word/:token with /word/(^:([a-z]+))
    $pattern =~ s!
      (\:([a-z]+))
    !
      if ( $2 ) {
        "([^/]+)"
      }
    !gex;

    "^$pattern\$";
  };

  return $pattern;
}

sub run {

}

1;
```

When the test cases run and I Dump e.g $resp in ## 4. test ## the returned value is not some version of "Hello kitty" but 'GET'.

Here is the output of the test

1..4
ok 1
ok 2
ok 3
ok 4

Why do all the subroutines return 'GET', I don't see where I generate this output.

I know a ton of similar frameworks exists, I am just doing this for fun :)

Comment: `sub connect` is returning `$self->{method} = $self->{env}->{REQUEST_METHOD};`

Comment: Also `%ENV->{'REQUEST_URI'}` is incorrect, Perl even tells you this (`Using a hash as a reference is deprecated at test-router.pl line 20.`) .. you probably want to use `$ENV` and drop the assignment arrow.

Comment: Did you mean `$router->connect(...); $resp = $router->run();` ?

Comment: Also see: http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.123/lib/Perl/Critic/Policy/Subroutines/RequireFinalReturn.pm

Comment: David K-J (facepalm) of cause, totally stupid... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code to work/not error. Take it or leave it ;)

`CGI/Router.pm`:

Things changed:

1. `build_pattern` returns a compiled regex via `qr/$pattern/`
2. `connect` param handling is less confusing. You were taking `$self, @args` off `@_`, but then taking `$req, $subr` from `@args` and doing nothing else with it. So I moved them up
3. `connect` returns the value of `run`
4. `$foo = $bar if !defined $foo;` is better written as `$foo //= $bar;`. Similar to `$foo ||= $bar` but checks for definedness rather than truth.

Code:

```
package CGI::Router;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'CGI';
use Carp;

use Data::Dumper;

sub connect {
    my ( $self, $req, $subr ) = @_;

    $self->{routes} //= {};
    $self->{env}    //= \%ENV;

    if ( !exists $self->{routes}->{$req} ) {
        $self->{routes}->{$req} = {
            handler => $subr,
            pattern => $self->build_pattern($req),
            method  => $req =~ /^(GET|PUT|POST|DELETE)/
        };
    }
    else {
        Carp::croak("Similar request already exists $req!");
    }

    # Get current request destination
    # TODO: Add that stupid IIS HTTP header
    $self->{destination} = $self->{env}->{REQUEST_URI};
    $self->{method}      = $self->{env}->{REQUEST_METHOD};

    return $self->run();
}

sub build_pattern {
    my ( $self, $pattern ) = @_;

    $pattern =~ s/(GET|POST|PUT|DELETE)\s?//i;

    $pattern = do {

        # Replace something like /word/:token with /word/(^:([a-z]+))
        $pattern =~ s!
      (\:([a-z]+))
    !
      if ( $2 ) {
        "([^/]+)"
      }
    !gex;

        "^$pattern\$";
    };

    return qr/$pattern/;
}

sub run {
    my $self = shift;

    my $router;
    my @params;

    foreach my $key ( keys %{ $self->{routes} } ) {
        my $route = $self->{routes}->{$key};

        if (   $self->{method} eq $route->{method}
            && $self->{destination} =~ $route->{pattern} )
        {

            @params =
              $self->{destination} =~ $route->{pattern}; # Not fully working yet

            $router = $route;
        }
    }

    return $router->{handler}->(@params);
}

1;
```

`test-router.pl`:

Things changed:

1. The `BEGIN` block was doing setup that you ought not do for a test script. I.e. randomising the flow.. so I ditched that off
2. Added the environment variables for each test case

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Test::More tests => 4;

use CGI::Router;

my $router = CGI::Router->new;
my $resp;

## 1. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';
$resp = $router->connect('GET /', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello 1';
});
print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello 1' );

## 2. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/hello';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';
$resp = $router->connect('GET /hello', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello 2';
});
print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello 2' );

## 3. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/hello/kitty';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';
$resp = $router->connect('GET /hello/:who', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello 3';
});
print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello 3' );

## 4. test ##
$ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} = '/hello/kitty/kat';
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} = 'GET';
$resp = $router->connect('GET /hello/:who/:what', sub {
  # print Dumper @_;

  return 'Hello kitty kat';
});
print Dumper $resp;
ok( $resp eq 'Hello kitty kat' );
```

Comment: Using // wasn't an option the last time I played with Perl ;)